# Как подключить Awesomium вместо WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser, awesomium

И сколько будет весить проект?
И как все собрать в 1 файл, я так понял в папку с проектом надо добавлять кучу dll всяких... или я заблуждаюсь... просто смотрел какое-то видео, но там вебкит был.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Как подключить Awesomium вместо WebBrowser

Скачать установщик с официального сайта, выбрать Custom и отметить все галочки, потом зайти в ту папку куда установилось.
Найти там нативные сборки (такие, как awesomium.dll и icudt??.dll), закинуть их к себе в bin\Debug
Затем managed-сборки Awesomium.Core, Awesomium.Windows.Controls. По идее на них надо добавить ссылки прямо из той папки, где они лежат, но я их тоже в bin\Debug кладу, и добавляю ссылки - меню Проект > Добавить ссылку.
Просто не люблю, когда зависимостей нет в поле зрения. И далеко лезть тоже не люблю.
Чтобы добавить элемент в Window - кликните ПКМ по Панели элементов и опять же выберите вашу сборку, элемент появится на панели, добавьте его.

> И сколько будет весить проект?

Если убрать все PDB, XML, заменить пару DLL на packed (они лежат там же, где и обычные), в общем, ужать до предела всеми "родными" средствами - то всего будет 26.4 МБ.

Если нужен Flash - еще нужна библиотека NPSWF32????.dll, где ее следует искать - не знаю, я взял где попало (хорошо хоть цифровую подпись Adobe проверил) и весит еще 18.7 МБ.

> И как все собрать в 1 файл

.NET-сборки потом можно смержить в EXE с помощью ILMerge (но уже потом, сейчас не стоит). А вот нативные (а основной вес - это они), возможно, вообще никак. Но и не надо. Просто сделайте инсталлятор для своего приложения.